# Apache Ignite Support For Java 21

Tags: java, ignite, java-21

Does Apache Ignite Support Java 21 ?

It works with Java 17 when I added these parameter

```
--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

But when I try with java 21  it throws exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: jdk.internal.misc.JavaNioAccess class is
> unavailable. Please add the following parameters to JVM startup
> settings and restart the application: {parameters:
> --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-exports=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
> --illegal-access=permit }
> See https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/getting-started#section-running-ignite-with-java-9-10-11 for more information.

**And even I add new parameters, it throws the same exception**

I have checked docs and it does not mention Java 21
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java
[image]

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/setup)? Given it states it was tested on _"Oracle JDK 8, 11 or 17 Open JDK 8, 11 or 17, IBM JDK 8, 11 or 17"_, you can pretty much assume it does not (yet) support Java 21. Also, [this issue](https://github.com/apache/ignite/issues/10954) suggests that it will simply not work.

Comment: As I mention I have checked docs and it does not mention Java 21. But just wanted to ask community, maybe someone tried and solve in somehow.

Comment: You can safely expect a software needing that many `--add-opens` clauses to break at every Java update.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Ignite (2.15) needs some code changes to work with Java 21 (a couple of PRs have already been merged). I would expect to see them in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

2.16 is released and it works with JDK 21

Answer (score 0):

There is a related bug fix that will be part of Ignite 2.16

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-19652